# serialize two value with one method

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer with two fields as below:

```
first_installations_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
sec_installations_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_first_installation_date(self, obj):
    return self._extract_date(obj, key="first")

def get_first_installation_date(self, obj):
    return self._extract_date(obj, key="sec")
```

the method for both are the same, with a bit different.
Now for refactoring the code, I want to know, is that possible two have a method like:

```
first_installations_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source="get_installation_date", key="first")
sec_installations_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source="get_installation_date", key="sec")

def get_installation_date(self, obj, key):
   return self._extract_date(obj, key)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible in the way you want unless you create your custom field.

But what about this ? if you really need to "refactor" like that

```
first_installations_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
sec_installations_date = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def _get_installation_date(self, obj, key):
   return self._extract_date(obj, key)

def get_first_installations_date(self, obj):
    return self._get_installation_date(obj,key="first")

def get_sec_installations_date(self, obj):
    return self._get_installation_date(obj, key="sec")
```